# Issues retrieving Information from Mysql Database through PHP web Service for Xamarin App

Tags: php, mysql, json, xamarin.forms

I been working on a Xamarin Forms Apps for Android and iOS, using PHP as webservices to consult the Data Base, and it work most of the time however there are times that I'm not able to consult the Data Base to Populate certain fields (mostly listview or Pickers).

For example I have a Picker that should display names from a table in the Data Base and it shows this:

[image: Data Base Error in App]

This is the Else code when Filling the Picker from the Data Base here this part of Code of the Picker Filling:

```
private async void fillListaServidor()
    {
        try
        {
            UseManager manager = new UseManager();
            IEnumerable<fullServidor> result = await manager.listarServidores();

            if (result != null)
            {
                txtServidor.ItemsSource = result.ToList();

                Pickerlist = result.ToList();
                Finallist = new List<fullServidor>();

                foreach (var item in Pickerlist)
                {
                    var exit = Finallist.Where(i => i.fullname == item.fullname).ToList();
                    if (exit.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Finallist.Add(item);
                    }
                }


                //lstUsuarios.ItemsSource = result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error en Lista", "Favor vuelva a cargar Servidor no listo", "Aceptar", "Cancelar");

        }
```

This Extends from the Methon "ListarServidores()" which is located in my Controller and here that snippet of Code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<fullServidor>>listarServidores()
    {
        HttpClient client = getClient();

        var result = await client.GetAsync(URL + "listarUsuarios.php");

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<fullServidor>>(content);
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<fullServidor>();
    }
```

fullServidor is the Model that has all the elements of the DataBase Table consulted and the listarUsuarios.php web service has the following:

```
  <?php

$cnx=new PDO("mysql: host=localhost; dbname=databasename","username","password");
$res=$cnx->query("select servidores.id, servidores.nombre, servidores.apellido, usuarios.username, usuarios.activo, accesos.tipo_acceso from servidores INNER JOIN usuarios on servidores.id = usuarios.id_servidor INNER JOIN accesos on usuarios.id_acceso = accesos.id WHERE usuarios.activo = 'Si'");

$datos = array();

foreach ($res as $row){
    array_push($datos, array(
    'id' => $row['id'], 
    'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
    'apellido' => $row['apellido'], 
    'username' => $row['username'], 
    'activo' => $row['activo'], 
    'tipo_acceso' => $row['tipo_acceso'], 
    ));
}
echo utf8_encode(json_encode($datos));
?>
```

What can be possible wrong that not always brings the data and I have to reload? (btw: I took the data basename, username and password for security, but when I use this Php through browser I do get the information out of the database everytime).

Is there any thing I could do to avoid having to reload 40% of the time?

Comment: `catch (Exception e1)` - `e1` contains useful information about **exactly** what caused the error and you are just ignoring it.  You need to log it or look at in the debugger or do something with it

Comment: Sorry for that here is the information I get about e1: 

Java.IO.EOFException: \n not found: size=1 content=0d... 

Then a bunch of Giberish which I couldn't copy sorry, if there is a way to get that giberish from Visual Studio I can added any idea?

Comment: there are MANY existing posts on SO and elsewhere on the web about "Java.IO.EOFException" and Xamarin